# what does "call someone out on one's behaviour" mean?

Tags: meaning

For example, I am standing in a queue and suddenly a person cut it before me. I am going to call him out on it. What does that mean?

Comment: What do you understand/intend that phrase to mean in that context?

Comment: why would you say something if you don't know what it means?

Comment: This question can be answered by a [dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/call_someone_out), so it is off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

To "call someone out on" a behavior means to confront that person specifically about the behavior in question.

Comment: I'd guess it originates from sport, where a referee might call someone out of their usual position, to come over to the referee and get warned about something they did.